InfluxDB/fluxquery unexpected token trying to calculate the percent
I tried to calculate the percentage for fields: ldevID with the query below:
from(bucket: v.bucket)
|> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
|> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "LDEV")
|> filter(fn: (r) => r._field == "LDEV_IOPS")
|> group(columns: ["ldevID"])
|> sum()
|> drop(columns: ["_start", "_stop"])
|> map(fn: (r) => ({ r with _value: r._value / sum(r._value) * 100.0 }))

but i got this error:
invalid: compilation failed: error @8:50-8:63: expected comma in property list, got DOT error @8:55-8:62: unexpected token for property key: DOT (.)
Many thanks for any help.

i updated the query as folow but always with an error: from(bucket: v.bucket)
|> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
|> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == “LDEV”)
|> filter(fn: (r) => r._field == “LDEV_IOPS”)
|> group(columns: [“ldevID”])
|> sum()
|> map(fn: (r) => ({ r with _value: r._value / sum(v: r._value) * 100.0 }))
